# What's the difference between Matlab inbuilt fit function and the backslash operator?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, backslash

Are there any differences between Matlab inbuilt `fit` function and the backslash operator when fitting data using one of the models accounted by `fit`?

EDIT 1: I know how `fit` works.
EDIT 2: This question refers only to those problems that can be addressed using both `fit` and `\`, obviously. Namely: GLM. Please find attached an example in the comments.

Comment: How do you want to use the backslash operator (which solves a set of linear equations) to fit the model?

Comment: GLM. Example: 2nd order polynomial fit. 
y = c0 + c1*x + c2*x^2 = [1, x, x^2]*[c0; c1; c2] = X*c. 
c = X \ y

Comment: You should add this to your question. So far the question very unclear. Maybe you should first `fit` documentation. Briefly, `fit` works for linear and nonlinear curves and it involves lots of control parameters, such as tolerance and number of iterations. While `\` is a one step operation that might or might not work for just linear regression.

Comment: I know how `fit` works. I'm asking if there are any COMPUTATIONAL differences between `fit` and `\ ` when applied to the same problem. Of course problems that can be solved using only `fit` are not relevant to this question.